# Why do I have to Huawei test environment with advertising and formal environment without advertising

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

为啥我得华为测试环境有广告正式环境没有广告
Why do I have to Huawei test environment with advertising and formal environment without advertising

我已经配置了
I have configured

[image]

Comment: May i confirm was your app been tested verification and rollout? Is it going to release outside China or in China? If convenient, pls provide your APPID and request log for us to check.

Comment: Use adb command as below:
`adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.huawei.hwid/files/Log/HiAdKitLog.log ./`

Answer (score 0):

To request a formal advertisement, the app needs to be accepted by Huawei. After the acceptance is passed and the app is released, contact Huawei operation personnel to configure the advertisement. Then the app can receive the formal advertisement.

For details about test verification and rollout, see [this document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/distribution/monetize/ceshiyanzhengjishangxian-0000001085219714).